# Converting Range to Array of Cell Addresses Office Script

Tags: excel, typescript, office-scripts

I'm trying to work out how I can convert a selected range in to a list of selected cells. So far, I have the following code:

```
  workbook.getWorksheet("Sheet1").activate();
  var range = workbook.getSelectedRanges().getAddress();
  console.log(range);
```

However, I'm unsure how to convert this in to a list of cell addresses.
Ex [A1, A2, A3, B1, B2] I found [this code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40557625/iterate-through-range-selection), however it only works with Office.js, not OfficeScript.
Thanks.

Comment: Your question is not clear at all -- you want the user to select a range of cells and then output the value of those cells?  See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47543778/4717755) as a possible solution.

Comment: My apologies, I have edited the post. I hope it's more clear now?

Answer (score 1):

> Option 1: Get cell **reference**

```js
function main(workbook: ExcelScript.Workbook) {
    // workbook.getWorksheet("Sheet1").activate();
    let selectedSheet = workbook.getActiveWorksheet()
    var range = workbook.getSelectedRanges();
    var selectAreas = range.getAreas();
    let cellList: string[] = []
    selectAreas.forEach(areaRange => {
        let colCnt = areaRange.getColumnCount();
        let rowCnt = areaRange.getRowCount();
        for (let r = 0; r < rowCnt; r++) {
            let rowRange = areaRange.getRow(r);
            for (let c = 0; c < colCnt; c++) {
                let cellRange = rowRange.getCell(0, c);
                // get reference
                cellList.push(cellRange.getAddress().split("!")[1]);
                // get cell value
                // cellList.push(cellRange.getText());
            }
        }
    });
    console.log(cellList);
}
```

---

> Option 2: Get cell **Value**

The order to retrieve it: selection (Range) > Area > 2D Array > Item(cell). Of course, you can get same result with Option 1.

```js
function main(workbook: ExcelScript.Workbook) {
    // workbook.getWorksheet("Sheet1").activate();
    let selectedSheet = workbook.getActiveWorksheet()
    let selectAreas = workbook.getSelectedRanges().getAreas();
    let cellList:string [] = [];
    selectAreas.forEach(areaRange => {
        areaRange.getTexts().forEach(textRow => {
            textRow.forEach(textCell => {
                cellList.push(textCell);
            });
        });
    });
    console.log(cellList);
}
```